# slow command output scrolling in xterm + screen

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm, termcap

### Expected behaviour:

Output of `ls /*` whizzes by very quick.

### Actual Behaviour:

```
$ time ls /*
...
real    0m21.003s
user    0m0.082s
sys     0m0.095s
```

It takes 21 seconds for this command to complete. The lines scroll slowly. Something isn't right. I'm running this in `screen` which is running in `xterm`. I tried troubleshooting it but haven't figured out what's going on yet. Did find something strange though...

### Workaround:

For whatever reason executing this script I wrote makes it work as expected: http://sprunge.us/zdvZEO

```
$ fastout
...
$ time ls /*
...
real    0m1.375s
user    0m0.116s
sys     0m0.116s
```

Found this by chance by messing with some TERMCAP files (don't remember which ones) and noticing that the problem goes away when I `cat` (a portion of) the file to the terminal. What do you think could be going on and how could I properly fix this without relying on workarounds?

#### Edit1:

Tested this in `urxvt` with default settings, with the same `screen` session attached:

```
$ time ls /*
...
real    0m0.281s
user    0m0.051s
sys     0m0.080s
```

From this it looks like the problem has something to do with `xterm` or its settings.

#### Edit2:

To make sure it isn't any of my custom `xterm` settings that are doing this I've tried:

```
$ xrdb -remove
$ /bin/xterm
```

Same result.

Perhaps `xterm` isn't at fault and it's just how gnu `screen` responds to being ran from `xterm`?

Not sure yet but despite being so used to `xterm` for years I might just switch to `urxvt` which aside from not having this problem on my setup - also lets me block-select.

#### Edit3:

Found out that if I change
`hardstatus alwaysfirstline`
to
`hardstatus alwayslastline`
in .screenrc the problem goes away in `xterm` when running `screen` (the output whizzes by as expected). In `urxvt` both settings work OK. I could just change that setting and stick to `xterm` but I kind of want the bar at the top.

Comment: If you're messsing with termcap, what results have you seen when you run `ls /*` in xterm without screen?

Comment: @SottoVoce without `screen` in `xterm` I'm getting very similar results to what I get after running the workaround - which is around one and a half seconds (of "real"), which is still acceptable

Comment: @SottoVoce perhaps I misunderstood what you meant. When I run my workaround script http://sprunge.us/zdvZEO in `xterm` (without `screen`) it doesn't seem to be making any difference (and it's acceptable already as it is). In other words when I run my script in `screen` the output scrolls as if I wasn't running `screen` - if that makes sense.

Comment: You have described the conditions "after running the workaround" as good (or better) performance.  And you have just said you get that better performance when you don't use screen.  It kind of looks like screen is reducing the performance, so focusing on xterm may not be real useful.

Comment: @SottoVoce yes, that makes sense - furthermore, when I run `screen` without its usual custom settings in `xterm` - the `ls /*` command behaves as expected, very strange. checking further